# Spring basic form error 405

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Hi i got this error try to learn some of Spring Java framrework.
I got an 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported and i need some help to see what is my error on this

my controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("overcomandant/addSitio.asp")
public class addSitioController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addSitioForm() {

         ModelAndView asf = new ModelAndView();
         asf.setViewName("admin/addNewSite");
         asf.addObject("sitio", new Sitio());

         return asf;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="admin/addNewSite", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addSitioSubmit(Sitio st, ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("url", st.getUrl());
        model.addAttribute("nombre", st.getNombre());
        model.addAttribute("estado", st.getEstado());

        return "admin/exito";

     }

     @ModelAttribute("estadoLista")
     public Map<String,String> ListadoEstados() {

         Map<String, String> estado = new LinkedHashMap<>();
         estado.put("1","Activo");
         estado.put("2","Inactivo");
         estado.put("3","Testing");

         return estado;

    }

 }
```

and this is my form addNewSite.jsp

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="sitio">

                <div class="form-group">
                <form:label path="id">ID</form:label>
                <form:input path="id" cssClass="form-control"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <form:label path="url">URL</form:label>
                <form:input path="url" cssClass="form-control"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <form:label path="nombre">Nombre</form:label>
                <form:input path="nombre" cssClass="form-control"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <form:label path="estado">Estado</form:label>
                <form:select path="estado" cssClass="form-control">
                    <form:option value="0">Seleccione</form:option>
                    <form:options items="${estadoLista}" />
                </form:select>
                </div>

                    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary" /> 

            </form:form>
```

and the exito.js

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>

        <p><c:out value="${url}"></c:out></p>

    </body> 
 </html>
```

I try to understand what is worng.
The controller creates an object site adding the info form the form an then the otrer .jsp renders the new object created...

Comment: If your problem is resolved consider accepting the answer.

Comment: i came a cross with the answer in addNewSite.jsp in the form tag i miss put the action parameter some thing like this   <form:form action="addSitio.asp" method="POST" commandName="sitio"> and problem solve just like you tellme to do =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify your form action to correspond the method in your controller : admin/addNewSite.

The 405 error tells you that the form action is unknown.